# CSS cube animation not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, animation, firefox

I'am trying to create an animation with a cube in CSS.
The animation is perfectly working in Chrome, but not in Firefox.
As soon as the cube goes out of the viewport, the animation freezes.
However, the animation runs if I move the mouse during the animation.
Here is the code (Note : the animation launches when face 4 is clicked):

```js
//Retrieve elements
var leftArrow = document.getElementById("leftArrow");
var rightArrow = document.getElementById("rightArrow");
var frontFace = document.getElementById("face4");
var cube = document.getElementById("cube");


function rotateLeft()
{
    cube.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg) translateX(-150px)";
    cube.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease-out';
}


function rotateRight()
{
    cube.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg) translateX(-150px)";
    cube.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease-out';
}

function face4Click()
{
    cube.style.animation = "face4Anim 7s ease-out";
    document.getElementById('body').style.animation = 'fadeOut 2s linear 6s';
    launchpage();
}

function face1Click()
{
    console.log("face 1");
}

function launchpage()
{
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.location.href = 'index.html';
    }, 8000);
}
```

```css
/* Reset margins/paddings */
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body
{
    font-family: 'moon get!';
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

header, #content
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

footer
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 8em;
}

h1
{
    margin-top: 2em;
}

#content
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#leftArrow, #rightArrow
{
    margin-top: 10em;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}

#leftArrow
{
    border-right:100px solid blue;
}

#rightArrow
{
    border-left:100px solid blue;
}

#cube
{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: translateX(-150px);
    animation: rotation 2s ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 8em;
}

#cube div
{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}

#face1
{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#face2
{
    z-index: 2;
    transform-origin: center left;
    transform: translateX(300px) rotateY(-90deg);
}

#face3
{
    z-index: 2;
    transform-origin: center right;
    transform: translateX(-300px) rotateY(90deg);
}

#face4
{
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translateZ(300px);
}

#face5
{
    z-index: 2;
    transform-origin: center top;
    transform: translateY(300px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}

#face6
{
    z-index: 2;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform: translateY(-300px) rotateX(-90deg);
}


@keyframes translation
{
    from{transform: translateY(-700px) translateX(-150px)}
    to{transform: rotate(0) translateX(-150deg) translateY(0)}
}

@keyframes rotation
{
    from{transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(180deg) translateY(-1300px)translateX(-150px)}
to{transform: rotate(0) translateX(-150deg) translateY(0)}
}

@keyframes fadeOut
{
    from{opacity: 1}
    to{opacity: 0}
}

@keyframes face4Anim
{
    from{transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(-150px)}
    to{transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(-800px) translateX(-750px) scaleX(5) scaleY(5) scaleZ(5)}
}
```

```html
<body id="body">

    <header>
        <h1>JS Games</h1>
    </header>

<div id="content">
    <div id="leftArrow" onclick="rotateLeft()"></div>
    <div id="cube">
        <div id="face1" onclick="face1Click()">1</div>
        <div id="face2">2</div>
        <div id="face3">3</div>
        <div id="face4" onclick="face4Click()">4</div>
        <div id="face5"></div>
        <div id="face6">6</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightArrow" onclick="rotateRight()"></div>
</div>

<footer>
    <h5>Developed by Tony Piton</h5>
</footer>

</body>
```

Does anyone can help me ?